# Prevent Sql Injection On Web API 2 inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, sql-injection

Hi we have old API project which is build on ASP.NET (fxows.asmx ) soap service and now we are converting into WEB API 2.so in first phase we are not changing Business logic layer which have thousands of inline queries. my question is this how can we prevent SQL injection in this case ? because SQL parameter is not an option for us because too much change same goes for ORM integration like entity framework so my only guess is if we validate a string property for each input then may be we can prevent it. is there any other way ? also is there any easy way to validate each string property ?

i cannot copy exact code here because we are not allowed to do this so i am posting a dummy sample

we are executing query like this

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Entity where id =" +InputParameter;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader rdr = command .ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Please better describe the types of queries you are running.  Without knowing this, an exact answer cannot be given.

Comment: what does your data access code look like currently? it *sounds* like you're saying "moving to EF is too much work", but: that isn't the only option for preventing SQL injection; you can prevent SQL injection just fine using pretty much every data access mechanism; so again: what does your current data code look like?

Comment: Without having look on your code how the community member would assume? Show some glimpse of your code.

Comment: i will update the question

Comment: @MarcGravell updated sorry for that.

Comment: the edit you've just made wouldn't be susceptible to SQL injection *anyway*... do you have an example with user input?

Comment: Nothing in the sample query you have provided is injectable, there's no user input being provided to the query. :/

Comment: check now basically we are concatenating input parameters with almost every query on project.

Answer (score 2):

> because SQL parameter is not an option for us because too much change

You cannot fix SQL injection vulnerabilities without changing some code. It sounds like you want to do something cheap and cheerful, perhaps something that scans your html form inputs and disallows certain values, but that:

1. is not reliable (it is an arms race)
2. it breaks your application (making values that should be valid impossible to enter, which *really* annoys users)

However; tools exist that can make it *painless* to switch to parameterized code; 
let's say we start with with the example from the question:

```cs
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Entity where id =" +InputParameter;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
```

we can tweak that using "Dapper" to be (with `using Dapper;` at the top of the code file, and [consuming the Dapper package from nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/)):

```cs
var rdr = connection.ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM Entity where id = @id",
    new { id = InputParameter });
```

and *that's it*; it is *less* code, and is now fully safe from SQL injection.

Dapper also has many more advanced things it can do for you, such as processing the results of a query into objects - but: I'm guessing you want to minimize the changes, so : limiting yourself to `ExecuteReader` is a good place to start.

(as a minor note: because Dapper works against all ADO.NET providers, the reader you get back is an `IDataReader`, not a `SqlDataReader`; it should function the same, though)

Comment: we have like 20k+ queries so i don't think so it will be easier to use dapper in this case.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal then you have 20k+ queries that fundamentally require attention, regardless of how you do it; nothing can change that; this comes under the heading of "tech debt", and at some point: you need to pay it. Will there be work involved? yes. I can *guarantee you* that it will be cheaper to pay that cost and fix the problem, than to ignore it and get your app/site/whatever destroyed and data exfiltrated due to SQL injection

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal also: wait until you hear that `System.Data.SqlConnection` is now essentially deprecated, with `Microsoft.Data.SqlConnection` (a different type, in a package that ships separately to the framework; the API is the same, though) being the new preferred thing...

Comment: we are definitely going to do it later but we don't have enough time right now.

Answer (score 1):

Web API isn't the issue here, neither is your reluctance to use an ORM (which I often don't use myself).

The issue is that you're building your query by concatenating an input into the query text. This is always an SQL Injection hazard, and a performance limiter as well because it stops SQL Server from efficiently cacheing a query plan.

Instead of doing it like this, set your CommandText to `SELECT * FROM Entity where id = @InputParameter`. Define a new SqlParameter with a matching name, assign the value to that and add the parameter to your SqlCommand and you'll have an injection-proof and better performing query.